# Best way to modify hashmap from reference to the value

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::hash::{Hash};

fn test(data: &mut HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>) {
    match data.get("foo") {
        None => return,
        Some(xs) => {
            let xs: Vec<String> = xs.iter().map(|x| x.to_owned()).collect();
            // How to drop `data` here so that I can borrow `data`.
            for x in xs {
                // Mutable borrow occurs, because previous `data` is still in scope.
                data.remove(&x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work, as I mutable borrowed `data` again while the previous borrow is still in scope. However, I couldn't find an easy way to drop the binding of the previous borrowing.

Also, is there any better way to copy the `xs` so that I can modify the hashmap while iterating it.

Comment: [May be of help](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/#problem-case-2-conditional-control-flow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close to a solution. Once you have an independent vector, you can just move it out of the scope borrowing the map:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn test(data: &mut HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>) {
    let xs: Vec<String> = match data.get("foo") {
        None => return,
        Some(xs) => {
            xs.iter().map(|x| x.to_owned()).collect()
        }
    };
    for x in xs {
        data.remove(&x);
    }

}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=c9c7f49e5fb23a29d12ff089631b6a1c&version=undefined)